# django create custom form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

We could directly create a simple form by inheriting forms.Form. However, I want forms to be dynamically created based on the key-value specified by the admin. Consider, user provides a map as :

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "CharField"
  },
  {
    "key": "url",
    "value": "URLField"
  }
]
```

Based on the map given above how can I create a form which is equivalent to the class based form creation below:

```
from django import forms
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name')
    url = forms.URLField(label='url')
```

My current approach might be to iterate across each key-value pair and make a HTML form manually. Is it possible to create dynamic forms in django without having to write a class definition?

Comment: Where do you get the extra-attributes (`label`, `choices`, etc.) from?

Comment: For now, we could assume its a value of key. However, I would add metadata based on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in the **init** function of the form.

Pass in the mapping array as an extra keyword argument when creating the form, then pop it from the kwargs before calling the **init** method from super.

You can then use this to dynamically add fields to the form.

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self , *args, **kwargs):
        field_mapping_array = kwargs.pop('field_mapping_array') 
        super(CommentFrom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        

        for field_type in field_mapping_array:
            field_name = field_type['key'] # make sure keys are unique
            if field_type[value] == "CharField":
                self.fields[field_name] = form.CharField(...extra args here)     
             elif field_type['value'] == 'UrlField' :
                self.fields[field_name] = form.UrlField(...extra args here)  
             elif .... map other field types here....
```

When creating the form pass the field_mapping_array into the form class.

```
field_mapping = [
    {
        "key": "name",
        "value": "CharField"
     },
     {
       "key": "url",
       "value": "URLField"
     }
]
comment_form = CommentForm(field_mapping_array=field_mapping)
```